# Implement dictionary using singly linked circular list

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I was solving a problem in which i have to implement the dictionary operation insert,delete and search using singly linked, circular list. What are the running times of your procedures ?

1) Insert : It can be done in O(1) 
2) Deletion : It can be done in O(1) 
3) Search : I'm not sure of it . O(length_of_linked_list) is the worst case of it .

Can Search  be done in even fast running time ??

Comment: Should I assume your link list is sorted?

Comment: @AyushJain If u assume link list in sorted order than insert will not be implemented in O(1) .

Comment: Yes I was gonna say that. Then I guess searching cant be done in O(log(n)) time if it is not sorted. It should be O(n)

Comment: @AyushJain Which one is better ?  Insert O(1) , Search O(n) ....
or Insert(log n) and Seach (log n) ?

Comment: It depends on how you use your link list. If there are more search queries than insertion then searching should be fast and vice-versa.
And if you have small size link list then O(n) search is pretty much acceptable. But for a larger link list if search queries are more then it `should` be O(logn)

Comment: @AyushJain thx bro .. i think the search with O(lg n) will be a good approach ..... but wait how will i implement insert(Log n) ?? binary search ??

Comment: Have you ever heard about `Self-organising lists` or `Skip-list` ?
Well if not, then here are links for you. You can consult them.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-organizing-list-set-1-introduction/
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/skip-list/

Answer (score 0):

Insertion and search, both can't be done with O(1) (unless when you are using hashing).
There are mainly 3 possibilities:

1. Search O(nlogn) and insert O(1)
2. Search O(logn) and insert O(logn)
3. Search and insert both O(1)

First one is used for example during when you insert at the final position of your linked list and search with the iterations after the sorting (quick sort takes an average of nlogn) has been done. This is helpful when you got to maintain your database with less search usages than insert usages.
Second one is helpful for example when you sort on insertion and search with the help of k-ary search method, taking logn time. This is helpful e.g. in telephone directory, where there are more searches than insertion. Now a days, hashing techniques are more used to deal with such problems (O(1)).
So, using hashing and indexing, we can achieve this functionality of O(1) time search and insertion.
Deletion time is same as search since you can delete in 0 time just after you have found your element (plus a few more pointer shifting, not a big deal).

Comment: with all this possibilites(excluding hashing ) u taked about ,its better to have O(1) insert , O(1) delete and O(N) search . but thx for your help bro .  I look into the k-ary search method .

Comment: You are welcome my friend :) One thing I wanted to clarify is that deletion in O(1) can't be achieved using linked list. Suppose you have to delete an element in the linked list, you have to search for it first no matter your list is sorted or not. This will definitely take an O(some time != 1). Anyways, it's upto your choice and the functionality you want to provide which method you are gonna adopt.

Comment: we can delete in O(1) time .. look at this post .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793950/algorithm-for-deleting-one-element-in-an-single-linked-list-with-o1-complexity

Comment: That is the case when you have a pointer(reference) to the node which you are going to delete. Finding that node obviously not gonna take O(1).

Comment: yes yes correct .. that's why in my question i have written O(1) to delete .