# Delete a node in singly link list

Tags: c, data-structures, pointers, linked-list

How to delete a node in a singly link list with only one pointer pointing to node to be deleted?

[Start and end pointers are not known, the available information is pointer to node which should be deleted]

Answer (score 17):

You can delete a node without getting the previous node, by having it mimic the following node and deleting that one instead:

```
void delete(Node *n) {
  if (!is_sentinel(n->next)) {
    n->content = n->next->content;
    Node *next = n->next;
    n->next = n->next->next;
    free(next);
  } else {
    n->content = NULL;
    free(n->next);
    n->next = NULL;
  }
}
```

As you can see, you will need to deal specially for the last element.  I'm using a special node as a sentinel node to mark the ending which has `content` and `next` be `NULL`.

UPDATE: the lines `Node *next = n->next; n->next = n->next->next` basically shuffles the node content, and frees the node:  Image that you get a reference to node B to be deleted in:

```
   A           / To be deleted
  next   --->  B
              next  --->    C
                           next ---> *sentinel*
```

The first step is `n->content = n->next->content`: copy the content of the following node to the node to be "deleted":

```
   A           / To be deleted
  next   --->  C
              next  --->    C
                           next ---> *sentinel*
```

Then, modify the `next` points:

```
   A           / To be deleted
  next   --->  C       /----------------
              next  ---|    C          |
                           next ---> *sentinel*
```

The actually free the following element, getting to the final case:

```
   A           / To be deleted
  next   --->  C
              next  --->    *sentinel*
```

Comment: Node *next = n->next;
n->next = n->next->next;

can you please elaborate this more?

Comment: If linked list is long enough then will shifting contents be a feasible solution?

Comment: @unknown, yes, it would a feasible solution.  This approach might complicate aliasing (another code holds a reference to the affected nodes and such); but you'll have that anyway.

Comment: Note that this only works if you don't have pointers to the following node.

Comment: Note that shifting doesn't really happen. You just copy content of one node into another. Actual length of the list does not matter.

Answer (score 16):

Not possible.

There are hacks to mimic the deletion.

**But none of then will actually delete the node the pointer is pointing to.**

The popular solution of deleting the **following** node and copying its contents to the **actual** node to be deleted has side-effects if you have **external pointers** pointing to nodes in the list, in which case an external pointer pointing to the following node will become dangling.

You can find some discussion on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209/deleting-a-middle-node-from-a-single-linked-list-when-pointer-to-the-previous-nod).

Answer (score 4):

The only *sensible and safe* option under such restrictions is to *mark the node deleted* without actually unlinking it, deferring that to a later time.

Comment: Not the only option but a good one none-the-less so +1.  We do that in our system quite a bit with mark-unused / deferred deletes.