# Deleting in a linked list

Tags: c++, c

Given only a pointer to the node to be deleted , how do we delete the node in the linked list...?

Comment: Singly linked list? Doubly linked list?

Comment: If singly linked list then duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960562/delete-a-node-in-singly-link-list If doubly linked list...not worth asking in interview :)

Comment: Also, the solution from that duplicate is an ugly hack if the list's object is anything big (i.e. non-trivial or just expensive copy constructor). See codaddict's post there. Impractical interview questions are impractical. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is too ambiguous, and is likely that way for a reason (e.g. to spawn a conversation instead of test your actual knowledge of the data structure).  They are likely expecting you to ask "Is this a doubly linked list or a singly linked list?"  If it is a doubly linked list, its a simple matter:

```
curr->prev->next = curr->next;
curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
delete curr;
```

If it is a singly linked list, you must have the head node so you can find the previous node in the list.  So they are likely expecting you to ask if you have a pointer to the head node.  The pseudo-code would then be:

```
loop from head to end until test->next == curr
test->next = curr->next;
delete curr;
```

Alternatively, if you can modify the list (without the head node):

```
temp = curr->next;
curr->data = temp->data;
curr->next = temp->next;
delete temp;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, its just a trick.

Assuming `curr` is the address given, following would be the pseudo code:

```
to_delete = curr->next
curr->data = to_delete->data
curr->next = to_delete->next
delete to_delete
```

Essentially this just copies data and next pointer of next node in the list to the current node and deletes the next node.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants to delete `curr`, not `curr->next`.  Otherwise, the problem is too easy.  ;)

Comment: The same trick can be used to do insertion before the current node, insert a node after it and then swap the data; however the problems arise with this approach if anyone else holds a pointer to the node, it has been deleted or its data changed!

Comment: I have myself faced this question and i believe that he actually intends to delete the value and not the node itself :) (at least this was the expectation from me).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's almost impossible in singly-linked lists if you don't have any pointer to list head. You should always have a linked list head pointer.

Comment: Ok, in thread given by codaddict in comment to the question there is way to delete node, if you give as an argument it's predecessor.

Comment: While you should have the head pointer, it is not impossible to delete an item from a singly linked list without it (though you will technically be copying the next item to the current one and deleting the next one).  For a doubly linked list, it is trivial to delete without a head or tail pointer.

Comment: That's why I wrote almost impossible and the comment. As you noticed this method is not really deletion of node. If you had somewhere else pointer to the node next to one you "deleted" you will get segmentation faults when you'll try to do something with it. It's not acceptable to me.

Answer (score 1):

In a standard linked list implementation, you *have* to modify the node that points to the node being deleted. To modify it, you have to find it first. If you have a pointer to the list head, or any element prior to the one being deleted, you can find it by traversing the list. If not, there's no general solution to this problem.

You could get out of the situation by modifying the definition of a linked list to mark deleted nodes somehow (say, with a boolean attribute `deleted`), and in turn modify list traversal to skip such nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
You have a pointer to that node (say, node N). Meaning, you have access on that node.
If that node has pointer to it's front node and it's back node, then simply point the back node to the front node. And the front node to the back of your node N.

To illustrate: 
step 1:
---> [ node ] ---> [ node ] ---> [ node ] ---> 
<--- [  M   ] <--- [  N   ] <--- [  O   ] <--- etc...

step 2:
---> [ node ] -----------------> [ node ] ---> 
<--- [  M   ] <--- [node N] <--- [  O   ] <--- etc...

step 3:
---> [ node ] -----------------> [ node ] ---> 
<--- [  M   ] <----------------- [  O   ] <--- etc...

                                    [ node ] ---> (still points to node O)
      (still points to node M) <--- [  N   ]

step 4:
just point Node N to NULL
                                    [ node ] ---> NULL
                          NULL <--- [  N   ]

result:
---> [ node ] -----------------> [ node ] ---> 
<--- [  M   ] <----------------- [  O   ] <--- etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution if this is not the tail.

If it is a singly-linked list you just "swap" with the node next to yours and delete that one instead.

Assuming I have

```
struct Node
{
  T value;
   Node * next;
};
```

Solution would be something like:

```
void freeNode( Node * node )
{
   Node * next = node->next;
   if( next )
   {
      node->value = next->value;
      node->next = next->next;
      free( next ); 
   }
   // else I'm stuck!
}
```

The above sort of pseudo mix of C and C++.

If the node we have is the tail, and assuming that the tail is indicated by node->next == NULL, I cannot make the previous node into the tail so I cannot solve.