# Deleting node in linklist without knowing head of linklist

Tags: data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a middle node from a single linked list when pointer to the previous node is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209/deleting-a-middle-node-from-a-single-linked-list-when-pointer-to-the-previous-nod)

Signature of delete node is given as void delete(struct node *nodeToBeDeleted);
head of the linklist is not provided. Is there any way to delete nodeToBeDeleted node?

Comment: There are a few very similar questions here: http://www.google.ca/search?q=delete+node+from+linked+list+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

Copy data of the next node to current node.

Now next node containing current node's data becomes the node to be deleted.

Set next of current node to next of next node.

Code Snippet

```
void delete(struct node *nodeToBeDeleted)
{
    struct node *nextNode;
    if(nodeToBeDeleted == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    nextNode = nodeToBeDeleted ->next;

    nodeToBeDeleted ->data = nextNode->data;   

    nodeToBeDeleted->next = nextNode->next;

    delete nextNode;

    return;
}
```