# Deleting any node from a single linked list when only pointer to that node is given

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

This is a question posed to me in an interview.

"A single linked list is there in the memory. You have to delete a node. You need to write a function to delete that node, which takes only the address of the node to be deleted as input and nothing else(including head)"

I gave the answer similar to the one answered in the below post -- Copying the contents of the next node into the node to be deleted and deleting the next one.

[Deleting a middle node from a single linked list when pointer to the previous node is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209/deleting-a-middle-node-from-a-single-linked-list-when-pointer-to-the-previous-no)

But the interviewer asked me again, what if I pass the address of the last node. I told him, since the next will be a NULL, copy that NULL into the data field along with the address to the next node which is also NULL. Then he told me there will be a problem of dangling pointers... which I didn't understand a bit. Can some one please throw light into this problem ? Is there a generic solution to this ?

Update (Two days later) : A little bit additional. Considering there is no special node at the end of the list. And the last node points to NULL and if that node is given as input, how to make the before last node point to NULL. Or is it impossible ?

Simply put : If a node is given as input to a function, how to make the pointer that references it, point to NULL

Comment: Are you asking what is the dangling pointer issue? or how to solve it?

Comment: Both, actually I want to know about dangling pointer also..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dangling Pointer:

> (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_reference)
>
> Dangling pointers and wild pointers in computer programming are
>   pointers that do not point to a valid object of the appropriate type.
>   These are special cases of memory safety violations.
>
> Dangling pointers arise when an object is deleted or deallocated,
>   without modifying the value of the pointer, so that the pointer still
>   points to the memory location of the deallocated memory. As the system
>   may reallocate the previously freed memory to another process, if the
>   original program then dereferences the (now) dangling pointer,
>   unpredictable behavior may result, as the memory may now contain
>   completely different data.

In your answer, to delete the given node you actually delete the **next** node, which might be being referenced by a pointer. That's how dangling pointer problem arise.

(1) There are no outside references to the list, as you clarify in a note.
(2) Dangling pointer problem can arise, as the interviewer said.

Both (1) and (2) cannot be correct at the same time. Which means there is a misunderstanding somewhere.

About Deleting the Last Node:

> But the interviewer asked me again, what if I pass the address of the
>   last node. I told him, since the next will be a NULL, copy that NULL
>   into the data field along with the address to the next node which is
>   also NULL.

I think you are confusing these two things: (1) A pointer p that points to NULL, (2) A linked list node that has NULL in its data field.

Suppose the data structure is `a -> b -> c -> d`. Writing NULL to d's data field will not magicly make c to have a NULL pointer in its `next` field.

You can delete the last node **if the linked list always has a special last node** that will never be deleted. For example, `a -> b -> c -> d -> LAST` where LAST has a special value in its data field that denotes it is really the last element. Now to delete d, you could delete LAST and write the special value in d's data field.

Maybe these are exactly what you tried to tell during the interview, in which case there must have been some miscommunication between you and the interviewer.

Comment: Thanks for the wiki and en-lighting me on the dangling pointer issue. Regarding the statement (1), it's true that there are no outside references. And the only node that is pointing to the node we are deleting is the current node. Since we are copying the contents of the next one (mean the node to be deleted) to the current node, now no one is pointing to the node to be deleted. So, no dangling pointer issue will be there when we delete it. This point is clear. Regarding the last node, let me edit my question a little in a seperate paragraph about it

Comment: this is my answer to your updated question: it is impossible. Maybe you should post it as a new question if you want second opinions.

Answer (score 15):

Steps:

1. Copy data from Node(i+1) to Node(i)
2. Copy the NEXT of second Node(i+1) into a temporary variable.
3. Now Delete the second Node(i+1) // it doesn't require pointer to the previous node.

Function:

```cpp
void delete_node(node* node)
{
    node->Data = node->Next->Data;
    node* temp = node->Next->Next;
    delete(node->Next);
    node->Next = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Then there should be a check in the program whether the given node is the last node or not.

```cpp
void delete_node(node* node1) {
    node* search=head;
    if(node1==head) {
        head=head->next;
        search->next=NULL;
        node1->next=NULL;
    }
    while(search->next != node1)
        search=search->next;
    if(node1->next==NULL) {
       search->next=NULL;
    } else {
       search->next=node1->next;
       node1->next=NULL;
    }
    delete node1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are other elements that are pointing to the next node which will be copied to the current node and then deleted, then this operation will introduce a bug. So in your answer you should have emphasized that your solution only works if there are no outside references to the list.

Your solution works with the last node only if the data structure is augmented with a specific "last node" element. (If you are using Smalltalk, you can write `self become: nil` No other language has anything similar)

No, there is no generic solution if there are outside references to the list. I think the interviewer wanted to see whether you are really knowledgable in the subject matter or were just repeating a memorized answer.

Comment: It's a single linked list and also there are no outside references to it. My question is about NULL pointer reference problem that may arise when you try to copy the last node. Also, please note that in a single linked list, the last node points to NULL

Answer (score 1):

Probably your link list traversing might need to assume that any node that points to `null` is `null` node regardless of the value...

```
a->b->c->d->NULL
```

so `d` is `null` node and the node should not be considered as a node. this way you can save on using special values since they are not correct in a generic sense. other than that you will not have any other way for previous node to point to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void removeNode(Node node){
    /* if no node return null */
    if(node==null) return;

    /* if only 1 node then delete node */
    if(node.getNext()==null) {
        node = null;
        return ;
    }

    /* copy next node data to this node */
    node.data = node.getNext().data();

    /* store the next next node */
    Node second = node.getNext().getNext();

    /* remove next node */
    removeNode(node.getNext());

    /* set the copied node as next */
    node.setNext(second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**: `deleteNode()` has reference to node pointer.

Simple solution without a while loop. In `deleteNode()`, if case handles deletion of head and intermediate node and else handles deletion of last node.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{

public:
  int data;
  Node* next;

  Node(int d): data(d){}
};

void insert(Node* &head,  int data){
  Node *node = new Node(data);
  node->next = head;
  head = node;
}

void print(Node *head){
  Node *temp = head;
  while(temp !=NULL){
    cout << temp->data <<" ";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

void deleteNode(Node *&node){

  cout << "Deleting "<<node->data<<endl;
  if(node->next != NULL){
    Node *t = node->next;
    node->data = node->next->data;
    node->next = node->next->next;

    delete t;
  }else{
    delete node;
    node = NULL;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  Node *head = NULL;
  insert(head, 10);
  insert(head, 20);
  insert(head, 30);
  insert(head, 40);
  insert(head, 50);

  print(head);

  deleteNode(head->next); //delete 40
  deleteNode(head->next->next->next); //delete last node 10

  print(head);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the last node is given, instead of deleting it, assign it to a dummy node and while displaying the data we can check for ptr->next as dummy node and terminate there.

In case of dangling pointer, I believe when the pointer is freed(deallocated), it will become dangling pointer and so after freeing assign it to NULL.

Below will be my code snippet for this Question:

```
dummy-> data = NULL;
dummy-> next = NULL;
FUNC(del_ptr)
{
if (del_ptr->next == NULL )
{
del_ptr = dummy;
return;
}
struct node *next = del_ptr ->next;
del_ptr -> data = next -> data;
del_ptr -> next = next -> next;
free(next);
next=NULL;
}
```