# assigning nil to pointer

Tags: pointers, go

I'm trying to implement a delete() method to a list (no HEAD ref)

I find out that I can modify the parameter to a struct.

```
func (l *LinkedList) Delete(n *Node) {
    if n.next == nil {
        n = nil
    } else {
        current := &n
        *n = *n.next
        *current = nil
    }

}
```

The "else" part works fine, but deleting the last node does not modify the list

Tried using

```
*n = nil
```

But then I have the compile error.

> cannot use nil as type Node in assignment

Code complete in this playground:

http://play.golang.org/p/Dhzyd7QHEw

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant or not, but have you looked at the built in list?  http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/

Comment: Yes, this is more like how to implement a particular delete case. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just doing it wrong. I mean classic element removal from single linked list. Right way:

```
func (l *LinkedList) Delete(n *Node) {
    // if we want to delete the head element - just move the head pointer
    if l.head == n {
        l.head = n.next
        return
    }
    // otherwise find previous element to the one we are deleting
    current := l.head
    for current != nil && current.next != n {
        current = current.next
    }
    // and move that previous element next pointer to the next element
    if current != nil {
        current.next = n.next
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_NlJw_fPWQD

So what was wrong in your example? In your *Delete* function you are receiving a pointer to some node. This pointer is local to your function, it's like a local variable. It doesn't matter if  you assign nil to a local variable inside your function. Outside - no one will see such assignments. What you want to do - is to change the *next* pointer of the previous list item. This way the item will no longer be in the list. GC will remove the actual allocated memory.

**UPDATE:**

Since go pointers are "real" pointers, this can be implemented without special case for the head removal, by using an additional level of indirection, as suggested by Linus in his famous [TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/linus_torvalds_the_mind_behind_linux) (and earlier in [slashdot Q&A](https://meta.slashdot.org/story/12/10/11/0030249/linus-torvalds-answers-your-questions) - see "favorite hack" question):

```
func (l *LinkedList) Delete(n *Node) {
    // initialize indirect with the address of a head pointer
    indirect := &(l.head)
    // until indirect has address of a pointer to the node we're deleting
    for *indirect != n {
        // check that it's not the end of the list
        if (*indirect).next == nil {
            // the node we're tryign to delete is not in the list
            return
        }
        // set indirect to the address of the next pointer
        indirect = &(*indirect).next
    }
    // indirect has address of a pointer we need to modify to delete the node
    *indirect = n.next
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hDy3hB5LUME

IMO two levels of inderection is harder to understand than a simple special case for deleting the head element, but Linus is not exactly an ordinary developer like myself :)

Comment: thanks for your answer
Yes, Using the head is easy, part of the original question is how to do it if you only have a reference to the node to delete (No head)

`void delete_node(node* node)
{
    node->Data = node->Next->Data;
    node* temp = node->Next->Next;
    delete(node->Next);
    node->Next = temp;
}`

basically I'm trying to do this in go, in order to understand how pointers work.

[link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362896/deleting-any-node-from-a-single-linked-list-when-only-pointer-to-that-node-is-gi

Comment: @MarianoDM you can not do it with _single_ linked list without head. The C code you wrote works only for the case when you are deleting non-last element.

Comment: @Kluyg I think this does not work if you want to delete the head node

Comment: @Kluyg So is there anyway to implement this as Linus suggested in golang? https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1%2AGHFLYFB3vDQeakMyUGPglw.png

Comment: @SasanRose Sure you can, go has real pointers, so here you go: https://play.golang.org/p/7lQMDjRoEjP
IMO two levels of indirection is harder to understand than a simple special case for the head element, but Linus thinks otherwise :)