# Deleting node from singly-linked list and closing the gap in one go

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list, singly-linked-list

#### Backstory

I've been writing lots of linked list and node classes for school lately. When I write doubly-linked nodes, I typically use the destructor to stitch the gap that's made when I `delete` a node: doing so links the previous and next nodes together before this node...vanishes. With a singly-linked list, the destructor can't do that exactly, because we know where this node points, but not what points to it. I don't really like this, so I came up with an idea.

#### Proposal

```
LinkedList: n0 -> n1 -> n2 -> n3
```

When I call `delete n1`, I want the following to happen:

1. Since `n1` is not the end of its list (it points to something): The values from `n2` are copied into `n1`, including the pointer to the next node. `n1` now points to `n3`.
2. `n2`'s pointer to the next thing is set to `nullptr`.
3. Call `delete n2`. Since `n2` is now the end of its list (it points nowhere), deallocate its memory.

The pointer `n1` is unchanged; the memory it points to is still allocated, but modified. The memory pointed to by `n2` is deallocated. Anything that pointed to `n1` now *effectively* points to `n2`, since all the data was moved from `n2` into `n1`.

If I were using names for each node (actually manipulating nodes `n0`,`n1`, and so on in non-class code), I know this would be a bad idea, because it would look like this:

```
// n0 -> n1 -> n2 -> n3
delete n1;
// n0 -> n1 -> n3 // ?? we asked to delete n1, not n2
```

But I don't. All access to individual nodes starts with the list. So we'd see this:

```
// [0] -> [1] -> [2] -> [3]
delete (*list)[1]; // assume SLL::operator[] returns a pointer to a node
// [0] -> [1] -> [2] // good, list is one shorter
```

#### Questions

1. Is this possible? How? Destructor, overloading `delete`? Other black magic?
2. Is this a terrible, horrible, no good, very bad practice? Why or why not?

#### Discussion

My train of thought in answering the first question has so far alternated between doing this in the destructor and overloading the `delete` operator in the `Node` class. I stalled when I realized that I don't know when/where the member variables are actually deallocated (or even what exactly that looks like/means). Members of the `Node` class are created via something like `int i;`, not with `new`. I'm confused because I want to conditionally prevent the `delete` operation from actually deallocating what it's given, and I don't know whether that's possible, etc.

As for the second question, I have a sneaking suspicion that this is an atrocity and that code for it should never see the light of day. If it were okay, we'd have learned about it, right? I don't know about that. We learn an awful lot of ugly, inefficient, or otherwise annoying algorithms in intro classes. Beats me, so I figured I'd ask and maybe get some sage advice on style and such.

#### Notes

- The list and nodes are created using `new`. Nodes are typically created like so:

  ```
  sll->setHead(new Node(data0))
     ->append(new Node(data1))
     ->append(new Node(data2));
     // SLL::setHead and Node::append each return a pointer to an appropriate node
  ```
- This specific discussion is not part of the class/assignment. The task at hand could easily be completed with standard methods (traversing list and deleting the old-fashioned way). I'm just curious.
- I'm aware that linked lists are pretty bad in terms of random access performance. It's an [artificial constraint](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6627273) placed by the assignment.
- Comments on the technique of using the destructor in a doubly-linked node to close the gap are also welcome, if you feel so compelled.

Comment: Consider also this case: what if you need to delete the last node in the list? In that scenario you can't move the data from the next node and delete the next node. Consider using sentinel nodes instead of `null` for terminating the list.

Comment: Instead of trying to mess with `delete` and destructors, just use a struct for `Node` and handle stuff in the `erase(Node* n)` member function of the `LinkedList` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69209/9254539.

Comment: Definitely answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362896/deleting-any-node-from-a-single-linked-list-when-only-pointer-to-that-node-is-gi/13739444#13739444). (How did I miss that?) At least, this is what I want to do. Is there a way to wrap that into a simple `delete` call, or is that not worth the effort?

Comment: I'd vote to close as duplicate but I don't know how. Probably don't have the rep.

Comment: "I've been writing lots of linked list and node classes for school lately." That's a shame. You should be using std::list or std::forward_list, so you can concentrate on learning how to write actual programs in C++.

Comment: @JiveDadson I agree; I wish I could. It’s an algorithms class, so not about writing actual programs :/